# how to load a component dynamically in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid id="main">
      <v-card class="white lighten-4 elevation-3">

        <li v-for="stop in stop_name_arr">
          {{stop}}
        </li>

        <direct_bus_travel_time_in_between_stops>
        </direct_bus_travel_time_in_between_stops>

        <direct_bus_travel_distance_in_between_stops>
        </direct_bus_travel_distance_in_between_stops>

      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

i have two components `direct_bus_travel_time_in_between_stops` & `direct_bus_travel_distance_in_between_stops` to be loaded after `<li v-for="stop in stop_name_arr">{{stop}}</li>` has been executed completely .

Is there any way to append the components dynamically inside a function to load it when I want it to load ?

Comment: What determines when one or the other is shown? You might want to look into [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

Comment: there is a function that loads up the array -> `stop_name_arr` to reflect its content on the dom.

Comment: `v-if="stop_name_arr.length > 0"` probably works. If not, then set a flag or something when the the array is loaded.

Comment: can't I append the component dynamically,from my script,after i am done with loading the array?

Comment: Vue is typically a reflection of *state*. What you are suggesting is imperative instead of declarative and Vue will resist doing things that way.

Comment: got it  & that worked ! thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I very much think that you could use meta `component` tag which asynchronously loads the given component in it passed to `is` attribute.

Here's the code:

`<component is="direct_bus_travel_time_in_between_stops" > </component> <component is="direct_bus_travel_time_in_between_stops" > </component>`

You could add functions/events in this tag on which condition it will load.
I think this link would be helpful - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
which describes about binding component to use dynamically

Hope my approach was useful for you!

**UPDATE**: This answer was provided in reference to vue version 2.x. I am unaware of vue 3.x and haven't read 3.x docs. You can always submit an edit draft for vue 3.x compatible solution. Thanks!

Comment: This also works in Vue 3. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components Thank you for the tip!